# Не стабильная работа google капчи

Tags: php, recaptcha, captcha, google-recaptcha

Установил Google Recaptcha v3.

И при тесте на локальном хостинге все работает нормально, но на реальном постоянно считает пользователя за робота, всегда.

Я подумал, что может быть дело в коде.

```
define('SITE_KEY', '');
define('SECRET_KEY', '');
require 'db.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];

function getCaptcha($SecretKey) {
    $Response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".SECRET_KEY."&response={$SecretKey}");
    $Return = json_decode($Response);
    return $Return;
}
$Return = getCaptcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

    if($Return->success == true && $Return->score > 0.5){

      $username = strip_tags($username);
      $username = htmlspecialchars($username);
      if ($username == '') {
        echo 'Введите имя';
        exit();
      } else if(mb_strlen($username) < 2){
        echo 'Введите больше слов';
        exit();
      } else if(mb_strlen($username) > 55){
        echo 'Слишком много символов';
        exit();
      }

      $sql = 'INSERT INTO tasks(username) VALUES(:username)';
      $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute(['username' => $username]);
    }
    else{
        header('Location: robot.html');
        exit();
    }
```

Правильно ли я сделал последовательность?

Я имею в виду, что может быть надо функцию getCaptcha прям сразу сразу делать, а все остальное потом.

Может ли в этом быть причина?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А вы добавили домен реального сайт в настройках капчи на Гугле?

Comment: да, даже пробовал заново ключи пересоздать

Comment: Для обращения к recaptcha api вы используете file_get_contents. Эта функция требует, чтобы на сервере была включена опция  allow_url_fopen. Возможно из-за этого работает локально, но не работает на реальном сайте. Если нет возможности включить allow_url_fopen на хостинге, попробуйте реализовать код через CURL.

Comment: Включил, теперь возвращает null

Comment: function getCaptcha($SecretKey) {
    $Response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret_key."&response={$SecretKey}");
    $Return = json_decode($Response);
    return $Return;
}
$Return = getCaptcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
var_dump($Response);
    if($Return->success == true && $Return->score > 0.5){
      echo "человек";
    }
    else{
        echo "робот";
    }

Comment: возвращает null

Comment: Вот тут https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify сказано, что запрос должен быть POST. file_get_contents - по умолчанию GET. 
Вот тут описано как переделать на POST https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php#108309

Comment: Но у меня же на локальном работало и без этого? В вашем решении это настраивается в самом запросе, а не на стороне сервера.

Comment: Т.к. Recaptcha возвращает null вместо внятного ответа, я предполагаю, что запрос отправляется неверно. А вот как это с технической точки зрения объясняется, я пока не понял. Попробуйте запрашивать верификацию через cURL.

Comment: Все решилось само 0_o видимо это гугл шалил